# unable to locate package mssql-server on Raspbian

Tags: mysql, raspbian, 64bit

I bought a Raspberry Pi 4b to execute a bunch of scripts, updating an Azure SQL db.
For which, on my laptop running Deepin, I used mssql-tools (sqlcmd and bcp).
After setting it up according to Microsoft's instructions for Ubuntu ([install page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15)), I get an error when executing this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev
```

**"Unable to locate package mssql-tools"**

Unfortunately, I have a very limited knowledge of hardware and the Linux architecture.

[This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850607/mssql-on-ubuntu-cant-get-it-to-install) explains I need a 64-bit system.

I installed raspbian-nspawn-64:

> This project is a bootable, microSD card 64-bit kernel, 32-bit
>   Raspbian Buster 'Desktop' host OS + 64-bit Debian Buster guest OS
>   image for the Raspberry Pi 4 model B, and Pi 3 model B/B+ single board
>   computers (SBC). It is intended for users who would like to retain
>   their familiar Raspbian tools, desktop and repos, but who also need to
>   run one or more 64-bit only software components on their Pi.

As per [the creator's instructions](https://github.com/sakaki-/raspbian-nspawn-64), I opened a 64-bit 'guest container' in which I should be able to install and run a 64-bit application.

However, it fails again, with the exact same error message.

I checked the status of the guest container and it is up. All previous steps (import the public repository GPG keys, register the Microsoft Ubuntu repository and the update) worked well within that container.

I tried both answers from the linked thread, but it didn't solve the issue.
Running this command, however, doesn't return anything:

```
apt-cache search mssql-server
```